# Do I copy resp.Body?

Tags: go

I am learning go and I have the following code which works fine:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)  // get the html
   ...
doc, err := html.Parse(resp.Body)  // parse the html page
```

Now I want to print out the html first then do the parsing:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
   ...
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)  // this line is added, not working now...
doc, err := html.Parse(resp.Body)
```

I guess the reason is resp.Body is a reader, I can not call the read twice? Any idea how can I do this correctly? Copy the resp.Body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the client streams the response body from the network, it's not possible to read the body twice.

Read the response to a `[]byte` as you are already doing. Create a `io.Reader` on the bytes for the HTML parser using [bytes.NewReader](https://godoc.org/bytes#NewReader).

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
...
b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)  
doc, err := html.Parse(bytes.NewReader(b))
```

Comment: Thanks! why the original one is not working? I guess its due to I read it twice? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld you typically cannot read a stream twice. This is true in most languages. Depending on the implementation, streams might not keep all the data buffered in memory, instead they stream small sets of data as the client consumes them, they might even discard from memory the data once it has been read by the client (therefore making impossible to read it twice.)

Comment: Appreciate this response! `io.ReadAll()` to keep up with the times :)